# EF Puts wrong relationship in datatabse

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I got this project were a Operator can have many roles.
Let me start out with the code so you can see what i mean.

TDOperator:

```
[DisplayName("Operator")]
public class TDOperator
{


    public int TDOperatorId { get; set; }


    [DisplayName("First Name")]
    [Required]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Last Name")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    [DisplayName("Email Adress")]
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }




    [Required]
    public string Username { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = true)]
    public DateTime LastLogin { get; set; }



    public List<string> RoleNames
    {
        get
        {
            return Roles.Select(x => x.Name).ToList();

        }
    }


    public virtual ICollection<Role> Roles { get; set; }



    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Topdesk Username")]
    public string TDUserName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<TDOperator> Coaches { get; set; }
    public List<string> CoachNames
    {
        get
        {
            return Coaches.Select(x => x.ToString()).ToList();

        }
    }
    public virtual ICollection<TDOperator> Pupils { get; set; }
    public List<string> PupilNames
    {
        get
        {
            return Pupils.Select(x => x.ToString()).ToList();

        }
    }






    public override string ToString()
    {
        return this.FirstName + " " + this.LastName;
    }
}
```

And the one for Role

```
public class Role
{
    public int RoleID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Priority { get; set; }
}
```

Sorry for messy code I intent to clean that up later.

When i run this it Generated a database with 3 Tables with columns:

```
 - TDOperatorTDOperators
  1.TDOperator_TDOperatorId
  2.TDOperator_TDOperatorId1


 - TDOperators
  1.TDOperatorId
  2.FirstName
  3.LastName
  4.EmailAdress
  5.UserName
  6.PassWord
  7.LastLogin
  8.TDUsername 


 - Roles
  1.RoleId
  2.Name
  3.Priority
  4.TDOperator_TDOperatorId <<--- WTF!
```

The problem with this is that i can now only assign a role To 1 user. There can only be 1 admin and 1 user for example. It is supposed to create and extra Foreign Key table but it doesnt!

Please help out.

Comment: are you using code first approach ? can you show us your EntityTypeConfiguration classes ?

Comment: But according to the code you have  public virtual ICollection<Role> Roles { get; set; } in the TDOperator class, if not mistaken that creates a FK in Roles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not telling Entity Framework that you want the Roles -> Operators relationship.  Try adding this to your `Role` class.

```
public virtual ICollection<TDOperator> Operators { get; set; }
```

Comment: I will try this next week at my work.I think you are right and this will solve it.